# Bounding matrix-vector product norm

Tags: linear-algebra, approximation-theory

Let $A,B : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be diagonalizable matrices with $\lambda$ being the eigenvalue of maximal absolute value between them. Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Running a few computations on matrices I randomly picked seems to suggest that
$$ \left\| \left( \prod_{i = 1}^{n} A^{a_{i}}B^{b_{i}} \right)v \right\|_{2} \leq C\lambda^{n} $$
for all $n$, where $(a_{i},b_{i}) \in \lbrace (0,1),(1,0) \rbrace$ and $C$ is a fixed constant. Could this be true? Expanding $v$ as a linear combination of eigenvectors for $A,B$ and getting a nasty nested sum got me nowhere.

Comment: I should note that all of my computations had $B=PA$ where $P$ is a permutation matrix, but I'm going to guess that if it's true for this case, it's true in general....

Comment: This follows from the fact that
\begin{align}
\|Ax\|_2 \le \|A\|_{\operatorname{op}} \|x\|_2.
\end{align}

Comment: @JackyChong I see in the case that $A,B$ are symmetric that it follows quickly from this fact, but am still struggling to see how that may be used for non-symmetric $A,B$.

Comment: Could you point to where I need $A$ and $B$ to be symmetric?

Comment: I am thinking that if $A,B$ are symmetric, then $\left\| \prod_{i} A^{a_{i}}B^{b_{i}} \right\| \leq \prod_{i} \| A^{a_{i}} \| \|B^{b_{i}}\| \leq \lambda^{n}$. But otherwise, I'm unsure how the $\left\| \prod_{i} A^{a_{i}}B^{b_{i}} \right\| $ would be related to the maximal eigenvalue between $A$ and $B$ alone.